# Цикл по 2 файлам Excel (C# и Epplus)

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Подскажите как можно циклом сравнить 2 файла Excel с помощью Epplus. У меня не получается. Я могу найти совпадение, а нужно чтобы при нахождении проверял условием в строке по другому значению.

```
 foreach (var item in ws2.Cells["B:B"])
            {
                foreach (var item2 in ws.Cells["T:T"])
                {
                    if (item.Value.ToString() == item2.Value.ToString())
                    {
                        kol++;
                        label8.Text = kol.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Если делать через Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel то получается так:

```
for (i = 1; i < objXlsx.Columns[20].Cells[objXlsx.Rows.Count].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row; i++)
        {
            x_Count = objUserXlsx.Columns[2].Find(objXlsx.Columns[20].Cells[i], Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart);

            if (x_Count != null)
            {
                result++;
                bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[StrokaPochtamta].Cells[3].Value = result;

                if (objXlsx.Cells[i, 5].Value == "то что надо найти")
                {
                    resultat2++;
                }
                if (objXlsx.Cells[i, 4].Value == "то что надо найти")
                {
                    resultat3++;
                    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[StrokaPochtamta].Cells[5].Value = resultat3;
                }
                if (objXlsx.Cells[i, 4].Value == "то что надо найти")
                {
                    resultat4++;
                    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.Rows[StrokaPochtamta].Cells[6].Value = resultat4;
                }

            }
        }
```

А как такое сделать через Epplus.

Comment: уточните вопрос, не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Как получается? Не забывайте, я не сижу за вашей спиной, и ваши мысли не читаю!

Comment: Добавил изменения в основой текст. Может так понятней будет.

Comment: попробуйте сначала словами описать, то что у вас есть, и что хотите получить, пока вообще не понятно, что у вас там происходит.

Comment: Вот смотрите у меня есть два файла Excel, далее циклом прогоняю в первом файле в Columns(20) и ищу совпадения во втором файле в Columns(2) . Если совпало, то вывел кол-во совпадений. Далее проверяет другое условие в найденном совпадении.

Comment: И в чем проблема? Сделайте вложенные if'ы, если совпало, то попадаете в тело if и выполняете следующий подсчет и так далее.

Comment: делал не канает так.

Comment: потому что следующий if должен находиться в ws.Cells["D:D"]